# update index of combobox when user selects a different index than listed from a swing GUI form?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

when selecting different option in a combobox the index does not change and will always default to the already selected difficulty

```
public class ClickingGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int difficulty;

    public int diffRec() {
        //     diff = difficulty;

        switch (comboDifficulty.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
                difficulty = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                difficulty = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                difficulty = 2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return (difficulty);

    }

    public ClickingGame() {

        initComponents();
    }


private void comboDifficultyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                


 }
```

Comment: Wait, what? Can you clarify your problem and code a bit more?

Comment: Have you tried putting in some `System.out.println` statements in to test your logic?  Have you tried calling `diffRec` from `comboDifficultyActionPerformed` so it applies the  value to the `difficulty` field?

Comment: the selected index defaults to 1, which is medium. when you choose any other option in the combo box like easy or hard, they have different index's, (easy = 0, hard = 2), when you select a different difficulty, the index of the combobox should update to match the index of the difficulty, but it always stays as one and does not update to a different index.

Comment: This looks incomplete code. However `diffRec()` method looks validation method. `JComboBox` provides API for setting the selected index programatically using `setSelectedIndex(...)`. You can put this line of code in `ItemListener` or `ActionListener`. Just in case to prevent looping of events add the check before setting the index programatically.

Comment: @KamalSingh so in action listener I add  setSelectedIndex(difficulty); ?

Comment: Yes. But be aware of the event looping (You can add check like `if(diffRec() == 0)` means for only invalid selection call `setSelectedIndex(...)`).

Comment: @KamalSingh im getting an error saying that setSelectedIndex "cannot find symbol" in actionlistener

Comment: This method is part of `JComboBox` not of `ActionListener`.

Comment: @KamalSingh in the comboDifficultyActionPerformed or in its own method because I don't have one because I used the swing Gui form

Comment: You have an instance of `comboDifficulty` available in `ClickGame` class. You have written code in question to `getSelectedIndex` Here in this class you can write the logic to `setSelectedIndex` too.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson the question code is not complete. It is fractional. Based upon that I can give idea only what it should look like. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `ActionListener` to the ComboBox, wich is calling the `diffRec` method (to update the selected difficulty). Like so:

```
   comboDifficulty.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            diffRec();
        }
    });
```

> Your code snippet does not show all relevent parts, so please check
>   the answer and tell me if it solves your problem.